# loop through result set of a stored procedure and update tables

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have two database servers. I am getting updated Item details from one database server using a procedure which saved in the other database. Then I want to update the other database's Item table with the result set of procedure.
If there are new items add in the first database I want to insert those records too

Please suggest me a optimum way to done this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on @Dan Bracuk answer, write the data to the temp table, then update the records in your mirrored database with the values that are in the temp table, all by the primary key. (Since it sounds like it's an exact mirror, I'm assuming you are preserving all keys in the table).

Then, when that's done, you can select all records from the temp table that DON'T exist in the real table, then do an insert of those records.

It ends up being 2 statements (update, then insert), which is FAR better than doing RBAR.

Answer (score 1):

Put the result set into a temporary table and update the other db's table from that temp table.  This allows you to run a single update query instead of using a loop.

The details depend on the rdbms you are using, something you didn't specify.  You'll also have to ensure that the appropriate permissions are set up on both dbs.

Comment: If there are new records inserted in the other database server(which I received the data) I want to add those records too.